# Will the wife be questioned about her husbands sins?

Tags: sin, hisbah

I need to know whether I will be questioned about my husband’s sins. My husband does not pray namaz. He is a Muslim but does not believe in praying. I tried to make him understand that without namaz he will have a tough time in the afterlife, but he doesn’t believe me and says his belief in Allah is and should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wife is obligated to correct her husband's behavior through means such as education and advice, and possibly asking someone who has authority over the husband. This obligation comes under the purview of 'enjoining right and forbidding wrong'.

> والمؤمنون والمؤمنات بعضهم أولياء بعض يأمرون بالمعروف وينهون عن المنكر
>
> The believing men and believing women are allies of one another. They enjoin what is right and forbid what is wrong.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:71](https://quran.com/9/71?translations=20)</sup>

> من رأى منكم منكرا فليغيره بيده فإن لم يستطع فبلسانه فإن لم يستطع فبقلبه وذلك أضعف الإيمان
>
> Whoever among you sees an evil action, let him change it with his hand; if he cannot, then with his tongue; and if he cannot, then with his heart and that is the weakest
> of faith.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/84)</sup>

If the above is not effective then the wife will not be blamed. A person is only held accountable for what they can control.

Further, if the husband does not pray, then this can be either of the following cases:

- He does not pray out of laziness, but acknowledges that praying is required. However he hopes for forgiveness from Allah.
- He believes that praying is not required in Islam.

The second case (at least) is Kufr and would annul the marriage. The wife can no longer remain with the husband rather she must separate, and she would be a sinner if she remains with him.

Comment: Also see: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62173/